# Dimension of direct limit of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $K$ be a field and let $\{V_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a collection of finite-dimensional spaces over $K$, together with maps $\varphi_i: V_i \rightarrow V_{i+1}$. I am interested in the dimension as a $K$-vector space of the direct limit $V=\varinjlim V_i$.

Clearly, if the maps $\varphi_i$ are eventually injective (injective for $i\gg 0$), the sequence $a_i=\dim_K(V_i)$ is non-decreasing, and if the maps $\varphi_i$ are eventually surjective, the sequence $a_i$ is non-increasing. In particular, if there is a $j$ such that $\varphi_i$ is an isomorphism for $i \ge j$, then $a_i$ is an eventually constant sequence, with limit $L=a_j$.

My suspicion is that $\dim_K(V)=L$ as well. If $\{v_1,\cdots,v_L\}$ is a basis of $V_j$, then for any $k\ge 0$, if we write: $$w_i = \varphi_{k+j-1}\circ \varphi_{k+j-2}\circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{j}(v_i),$$ then $\{w_1,\cdots,w_L\}$ is a basis for $V_{j+k}$. Then, letting $[\bullet]$ denote the image of an element of $V_i$ in the direct limit $V$, we must have $\{[v_1],\cdots,[v_L]\}$ is a basis of $V$.

This set should be $K$-linearly independent, since any $K$-relation: $$\sum \lambda_i [v_i] = \left[\sum \lambda_i v_i\right] = \left[\varphi_i\left(\sum\lambda_i v_i\right)\right]=\cdots$$ will vanish if and only if $\sum \lambda_i v_i = 0$ if and only if $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i$. Further, if $w \in V_k$ for some $k$, if $k\ge j$ then $w$ is the image of a vector $\sum_i \lambda_i v_i$ under the appropriate composition of the $\varphi$ maps, and if $k<j$, then: $$[w]=\left[\varphi_{j-1}\circ \cdots \circ \varphi_{k}(w)\right] = \sum \lambda_i [v_i]$$ so that $\{[v_1],\cdots,[v_L]\}$ forms a spanning set as well.

Does this seem like the correct reasoning?

Comment: I now believe that this is a more-or-less complete proof of the stated fact for future reference.